# PHP Procedural combined with OOP

Tags: php, oop, procedural-programming

I have been coding some OOP in PHP today and after some time, I figured that you can actually combine the two ways of writing PHP, procedural and OOP. My question is, is it considered bad practise to combine them, should I stick to one of them? Or is it even better coding if you can combine them to make it work perfectly the way you want?

Comment: Evaluating which kind of coding is "better" is dependent on your own definition of "better" (which may not even remain fixed across time and/or space) and therefore very subjective.

Comment: So I can combine these with no problem if I believe it's the best way for my application?

Comment: How is anyone supposed to answer that question? Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will always have to have some "procedural code" in PHP. For instance, any plain algorithm you write *inside* a class method is going to be mostly procedural. Also, PHP has procedural entrance points only. Meaning, in Java for instance you have to create a class even to just get your application started. In PHP you *will* have to have at least one line of plain procedural code which instantiates an object before "OOP PHP" even begins.

So, yes, in practice you'll always mix the two. Use objects where appropriate and where they simplify code; don't force OOP on everything you possibly can even if it makes no sense.

Comment: Ah really good answer, exactly what I was looking for. Especially the fact of forcing uneccesary small things into classes and objects. I will then combine these two for the most simplified and easy-understanding coding. Thanks